# Copying a changing object to inside a block, so the block has the correct value

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have this loop that has this `NSDictionary`. Every turn, this `NSDictionary` is created with new values. The problem is that this loop fires an async block to be executed. Something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  NSDictionary *aDict = [self fillDictWithCurrentValues];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       executeBlock(aDict);
  });
}
```

My problem is this. I want this block to execute with the dictionary passed to it but because the loop will execute faster, it will go out of scope when `executeBlock` runs. So, two questions:

1. I suspect every block will hold a reference to its correspondent `aDict`, so they will not crash even if they execute when the caller is out of scope, right?
2. `aDict` is a strong reference. Do I need to create a `__weak` version before calling the `dispatch_async` and a `__strong` reference inside the `dispatch_async` so there is no retain cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> 1. I suspect every block will hold a reference to its corresponding `aDict`, so they will not crash even if they execute when the caller is out of scope, right?

It will keep strong reference while the block runs, so you don't have to worry about it being deallocated on you.

That having been said, there is a question of what `fillDictWithCurrentValues` does. If it's creating a new dictionary each time, you're fine. But if it's returning some reference to some dictionary that is shared, this can be problematic. It just depends upon what this method is doing.

> 2. `aDict` is a strong reference. Do I need to create a `__weak` version before calling the `dispatch_async` and a `__strong` reference inside the `dispatch_async` so there is no retain cycle?

There's no strong reference cycle because when `dispatch_async` is done running the block, the block will be released.

You might still use the `weakSelf` pattern if (a) there's a possibility that `self` might be deallocated before the closures are done running; and (b) you think it's important that the closures don't prevent that from happening. But usually, when dispatching updates back to the main queue (which you only do with very fast routines), you don't worry about it.

Comment: I was needing to check that out to be sure. Thanks!